# angularjs - Cross-Domain Posting Error

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to use a website  of mine as the mysql backend for my angularjs app but when i try to post data to the server i run into this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.domain.com/backend_script.php.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '127.0.0.1:60728' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

(I removed the `https://` and stuff because im too low in rep to post links)

I added this in the top of my php file on the domain just to test but its still not working with the header set, this is what my script looks like.

```
<?php
    require_once 'adb-functions.php';

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:60728/');

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $q = trim($data->query);
    $all = $data->all;
    //print_r(2);
    function render($query)
    {
        global $q;

        $renderedQb = '';
        preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $q, $commands);
        //print_r($commands[0]);
        $commands = $commands[0];
        if($commands[0] ==="get"){
            if(trim($commands[1]) === "all") { 
                $renderedQ = "SELECT * FROM `".$commands[2]."`;"; 
                return $renderedQ;
            }
            elseif (!empty($commands[4])) {
                if($commands[4]==='spec')
                {
                    $renderedQ = "SELECT * FROM `".$commands[1]."` WHERE `".$commands[2]."`='".$commands[3]."';";
                    return $renderedQ;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'ERROR: Mismatch query template';
                }
            }
            else 
            {
               $renderedQ = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$commands[1].'` WHERE id='.$commands[2].';';
               return $renderedQ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $query;
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        $query = $handler->query(render($q));
        if($query){

                if($all==true){
                    print_r(json_encode($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
                }
                else
                {
                    print_r(json_encode($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
                }

        }else{
            //echo 'Error';
        }
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo $e;   
    }
?>
```

the rest of the script is just the execution of the query which is sent from a factory function i made in angularjs here.

```
fact.get = function(query, all){ return $http.post('https://example.com/script.php', {'query': query, 'all': all}); };
```

is there a way to set the headers in angularjs? or even a totally different way to accomplish this in general?

Comment: More to CORS than one header....see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966. Note that preflight request won't have data payload

Comment: preflight requests? and thanks im gonna check it out now

Comment: I seen the function he created, so would the HTTP_ORIGIN server variable be set to the address trying to post data?

Comment: SHould read the docs about how CORS works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: As for origin...I have used that code (with exception of adding some verbs to it) and will work as it is